# I can't access user input inside a loop

Tags: c

In my code, if the user inputs for example 2 for m, and 10111011 for the array n, the output is supposed to be 185, which comes from 2^7*1 + 2^6*0 + 2^5*1 + 2^4*1 + 2^3*1 + 2^2*0 + 2^1*0 + 2^0*1. When I run the code, I realize that m becomes 0 in the loop instead of the user input. How do I modify my code so that m becomes the user input inside the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int m, i=0, a=0, q;
    char n[8];
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%s", &n);
    while (i<8){
        q=n[i]-'0';
        a+=(int)(pow(m, 7-i)+0.5)*q;
        i++;

    }
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in order to properly read 8 chars, you should allocate n to be of size 9 (to also account for the terminating 0 char)

Comment: `scanf("%s", &n);` -> `scanf("%s", n);`. I'd advise to use `gcc -Wall` for compiler.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring your variables, add your `printf`.  For example: `printf("Enter a number: ");`  'm' is then scanned and used in your while loop.  You have it set up to accept an 'n' value as well.  If you don't need a 'n' value from user, then take out the `scanf` for 'n'.  I'm not sure if this is helpful.